# Get the X,Y co-ordinates on Simple click and OnLongClickListener in Android

Tags: android

I am working on a project and in it there is a need of getting the X and Y coordinates where the user simple click and long click so that it may differentiate after the click. I am trying as

```
lineView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i(TAG,"In Simple Click");
        lineView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
                Log.i(TAG,"In Simple ON Touched");
                x = (int)event.getX();
                y = (int)event.getY();
                x1=lineView.getLeft();
                x2=lineView.getRight();
                return false;
            }
        });
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

**Output**

On running the code first time. When I click on the line it gives;

```
 In Simple Click
```

and stops. Then I click on the line second time, it gives;

```
In Simple ON Touched
In Simple ON Touched
In Simple Click
```

**Why it stops on first click?** On second time clicking, I think yes it is working fine.

Comment: You are setting up the onTouch only AFTER the onclick() is called the first time. Move the lineView.setOnTouchListener all the way to the bottom of the code shown.

Comment: @GroovyDotCom **Only AFTER**? Should I add it before the `onclick`?

Comment: After the });  at the end of what you posted

Comment: or at the beginning, before setting onClickListener

Comment: Either way. Point is that both setOnClickListener and setOnTouchListener should be one after the other - not one inside the other.